# Novel about intelligent animals in an interplanetary war

Tags: story-identification, animals

This novel is a pre-1985 sci-fi novel that involves an interplanetary war and a group of intelligent animals (including one possibly named Lucy).

The most intelligent animal is a whale. At some point the character Lucy dies, and the other characters are able to communicate with her at her funeral somehow.

Can anyone identify this novel?

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE *Correna*! Currently this is not a question. Is this supposed to be a request for a [tag:story-identification]? If so, please [edit] your question to use that tag and add an explicit question that you are searching for this book. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: Children of Time by Adrian Tchaikovsky sounds similar and had sentient spiders and some other insects but was published in 2016.  Main character was named Portia.

Comment: Shades of "Startide Rising" by David Brin, but there were intelligent dolphins and chimpanzees, not whales.   Lots of different kinds of aliens.   And I don't remember whether the skirmishes were actually part of an interplanetary *war* exactly.....  bit of a long shot so I'm posting a comment rather than an answer.